# Camera live View in apple watch

Tags: camera, watchkit

On 3/9 apple demo.
They show how to use apple watch to see the camera live view and open the garage door.

I think they should integrate with HomeKit to control the garage door,
but how to get the camera live view??

Do these live view images come from iphone app?
then using bluetooth to pass the image data to watch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS parent app to the Watch app most likely integrates with HomeKit to control the garage door and the webcam.

In order to display the images from the webcam on the Watch, they are most likely writing those images into the [Shared App Group](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html) between the iOS app and the Watch Extension using [MMWormhole](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole) or a similar approach. They then read the images from the App Group and push them to the Watch over bluetooth and WiFi using the `WKInterfaceDevice` [addCachedImage(_:name:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceDevice_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceDevice/addCachedImage:name:) method. Once the image is uploaded to the Watch, it can then displayed on the Watch using a `WKInterfaceImage` or `WKInterfaceGroup` background image.

Comment: App group no more shares data between Apple watch and phone. 
For smooth live preview, there must be another way.