# Camera feed from iPhone to Watch and image editing

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-watch

Even with the release of WatchOS2, it seems developers still can't access the iPhone's camera for a live feed/stream. So I was wondering for different ways this can be done, basically I want to see on my apple watch, what is visible on my iPhone's camera.
Apple's builtin camera app (in watch) does this and so does the garage door control app.

I read a approach to the above problem in this post and found it quite possible, but still had a few questions and doubts:
[Camera live View in apple watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29060830/camera-live-view-in-apple-watch/29063468#29063468)

- At what frame rate should the images be captured at ? For example,
  for a 10frames/second, should a method to capture image be fired at
  0.1second ?
- Aside this, the image will be shared from iPhone to Watch using Shared App Group or MMWormHole ? Or is MMWH just for
  "notifications" between devices on whats going on ?
- Secondly, do I
  need to save the image each time physically on device, transfer it
  and delete it (from iphone and Apple Watch) after next image comes in, or
  just do so using a imageObject ?

Aside this, I also want to show a overlay frame over the camera feed (like how image editing apps in iPhone show frames, etc.).
So, for this, should I be merging/overlaying my frame image over the feed image directly on the iPhone part before sending the image frame over to the watch ?